# hello.js having error with google login

Tags: javascript, authentication, hello.js

im using Hello.js to login with facebook and google. Facebook login works perfectly fine, but when I login with google. it pops up, asks user for email and password and after that it returns, 403 GET https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me?access_token=[my_access_token]. Below is my code for login

```
<a class="btn btn-default btn-block" onclick="hello('google').login({
    scope: {
        basic: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',
       }
})">Sign up with Google</a>
```